# Javascript array inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I apologize in advance if my post is formatting incorrectly as I am a newbie with all this or if this is a duplicate post and I am just not sue the correct search terms.

With HTML / CSS / Javascript, I am trying to:

- display a list of my work using a script in my scripts.js file, populated by an array in my work.js file (I have this part working)
- then, when a visitor to my site clicks on one of those images, the content opens in a bootstrap modal with content dynamically loaded from my works.js file.

I am guessing I need to add some further js to the // WORK SECTION script, but not sure how to incorporate the .click + the 'desc' field in a Bootstrap modal.

Currently my work.js file is a separate one that I am referencing. Also, not sure how to link the images here in this post as the text does display over the images. I have the site up at http://www.the-is.com, where the images show with the content from the work.js array, but it's not yet clickable in to the modal.

Thanks!

```js
// WORK SECTION (in script.js file)
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < works.length; ++i) {
    $("#work").append("\
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 project work-img'>\
            <div class='work-img'>\
            <img class='img-responsive' src='" + works[i].pic + "'>\
            <span class='info'><p class='project-label'>Project:</p> " + works[i].title + "</span>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    ");
  };
});


// PROJECT ARRAY (work.js)
var works = [{
    title: "Software package implementation",
    pic: "img/pencils.jpg",
    desc: "I led over"
  }, {
    title: "ProProfs documentation",
    pic: "img/planning.jpg",
    desc: "This project was for"
  }, {
    title: "JIRA Agile Systems Setup",
    pic: "img/alphabet.jpg",
    desc: "To help enhance"
  }, {
    title: "Streamlining new site templates",
    pic: "img/writing.jpg",
    desc: "Our team decided"
  }, {
    title: "Excel decision list tool",
    pic: "img/lightbulb.jpg",
    desc: "Using"
  }, {
    title: "Analysis, testing and implementation of new storefront",
    pic: "img/rubics.jpg",
    desc: "The time"
  },

]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should probably not ask such a complex question but break it down into parts. Can you handle onClick? Add an image tag to a div? etc.

Comment: @RoyFalk, yes, image tag on a div is already included. I'm not sure where in the // WORK SECTION script to add the onClick. Within the `("#work").append` div classes, or does it need to be a separate script that I run?